# Invariant subspaces under linear transformation and its complexification

Tags: linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

The problem $77.6$ from Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces:

> If $A$ is a linear transformation on a real vector space $V$ and if a subspace $M$ of complexification $V^+$ is invariant under $A^+$, then $M^\perp \cap V$ is invariant under $A$.

The problem states that $M^\perp \cap V$ is invariant, but my solution proves that $M \cap V$ is.

Let $x \in M \cap V$, then $Ax = Ax + i\cdot A0 = A^+(x + i\cdot0) \in M$, by the fact that $x + i\cdot0 \in M$ and $M$ is invariant under $A^+$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Are you claiming that if $M\cap V$ is invariant under $A$, then so is $M^\perp \cap V$? You should also prove the statement directly.

Comment: You mean $M$ is invariant under $A^+$, not $A$. The proof looks okay.

Comment: I'm claiming that $M \cap V$ is invariant under $A$, but not necessarily $M^\perp \cap V$ as it stated in the exercise. Why would $M^\perp \cap V$ be an invariant under $A$ in general?

Comment: You're right; this can't be proved without additional assumptions on $A$. Must be a typo.

Comment: I encountered the same typo, and I'll add that $M^\perp\cap V$ is in fact invariant under $A^*$.